# How does CreateMutex() internally work?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Basically, it is used to make an application instance singleton.

I wish to know,
how it works internally and how does OS manage it ?

Comment: check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Answer (score 1):

It creates a system-wide object. How the OS manages it is a consealed implementation detail, you can only use the mutex trough the OS-supplied functions (like `ReleaseMutex()` for example).

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810047.aspx) has some information about the underlying details of mutexes. In general, a mutex created with the Windows CreateMutex function is a kernel-owned object, which means that a user level application must transition from user mode to kernel mode to acquire ownership of the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

This gives a few hints about internals

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266%28VS.85%29.aspx

If you are interested in algorithms wikipedia is a good starting point.
If you are interested in implementation, google linux source code semaphore.c